# File upload from html > mvc/api > remote server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, ftp

I have a file upload working on html, which calls a post on the api controller.

Could anyone provide / point me in the right direction of the code necessary to get the file out of the post and send that file to an ftp server?

If using an mvc controller is easier that is fine too, although I'd prefer api.

This is the code I currently have - but I don't know how to get an assembled file (an image here, I copy-pasted this from somewhere) out of this data nor how to send it to an ftp server.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/file/post")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        try
        {
            var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());
            var file = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault();

            if (file == null || file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName == null)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(ms);

                var byteArray = ms.ToArray();
            }


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this currently do? Where are you "trying to get an assembled file out of this data", and what does it do right now?

Comment: @krillgar I think everything is in my post; --- 

Currently does: file upload working on html, which calls a post on the api controller --- 

Where: public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post() & send that file to an ftp server ---

what does it do right now: file upload working on html, which calls a post on the api controller